# How do I minimize a list so there will only be only one of each element in python - in one line?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a function that will get 2 lists, find the intersection points between them, and return a new list with these intersection points, and the new list won't contain the same element more than once.
For example:

> intersection([1,2,3,4], [8,3,9])
> [3]

I've tried the following:

> print(list(filter(lambda x: x in list2, list1)))

The thing is, if do, for example:

> intersection([1,2,3,3,4], [8,3,9])

The result would be [3,3].

How do I make it so there will o only be one 3, in the same line of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use set and convert the result back to list as follow:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
l2 = [8, 3, 9]
list(set(l).intersection(set(l2)))
```

outpu:

```
[3]
```

Comment: This works, but `set.intersection(set(l), set(l2))` is a bit of a misuse; it's a method of `set`s, and is usually called *on* a set. This only works because you explicitly `set`ify the first argument (the `self` it would get if you called it on an actual `set`). The idiomatic approaches would be `set(l).intersection(l2)` (no need to `set`-ify arguments to method) or `set(l) & set(l2)` (operators require both sides to be `set`s).

Comment: You are absolutely right! I've updated my code to show exactly that. thanks!

Comment: hey, this worked.
However, another problem that I seem to face is that the set comes out sorted, if I understand right. 
for example, I pass:  
list1 = [5, 3]  
list2 = [5, 4, 3]  
This returns:   
[3. 5]
But I want it to return: [5, 3], like in the order the elements are in the list. Is there any way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: You can try installing OrderSet library from order_set package and it can do exactly what you are looking to achieve. ```from ordered_set import OrderedSet list(OrderedSet(list1).intersection(list2))``` would produce ```[5, 3] ``` [ordered-set](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try:
list(set(intersection([1,2,3,3,4], [8,3,9])))

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to pass by sets :

```
L = [1,2,3]
M = [4,2,2,3,3]

inter = list( set(L).intersection(M) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `set.intesection`:

```
def intersection(l1, l2):
    return list(set(l1).intersection(l2))

intersection([1,2,3,4], [8,3,9])
# [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

## How to get just a [3]

```
x = list(set(filter(lambda x: x in [1,2,3,3,4], [8,3,3,9])))
print(x)
```

output:

[3]